# C++ append string pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers, iterator

I am running into some unexpected string behavior when I append an **Iterator** to a string. Basically, I have a file that reads something along the lines of:

```
int x := 10;
print x;
```

I have a string already that contains the contents of this file, and I am iterating through it and simply removing whitespace right now.

```
void Lexer::parse()
{
    Pointer = Filestring.begin(); // both private members
    while(Pointer < Filestring.end())
    {
        if(is_whitespace(0)) // 0 indicates current Pointer position
        {
            advance(Pointer, 1);
            continue;
        }

        CurToken.append(&*Pointer); // CurToken is private member string
        advance(Pointer, 1);
    }

    cout << CurToken << endl;
}
```

By the end of the loop I would expect CurToken to be a string that contains nothing but the characters with all whitespace removed. Instead I get something like the following:

```
int x := 1 + 2;
print x;



nt x := 1 + 2;
print x;



t x := 1 + 2;
print x;
```

> ...

```
rint x;



int x;



nt x;



t x;



x;



;
```

I assume the issue is de-referencing the pointer, and if so, how can I append the current pointer position's character? If I do not de-refrence it, I end up with `invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’`

**Note:** is_whitespace() I have tested, and works as expected. So that can be ruled out as a possible problem.

Comment: Why are you not writing `it` instead of `Pointer` and do `++it` instead of `advance(Pointer,1)`? Also, why not [`std::isspace(*it)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) instead of `is_whitespace(0)`? You're unnecessarily making it complicated.

Comment: Pointer is a string iterator *

Comment: What does *Pointer return?  Why can't you use Pointer instead of &*Pointer?  It looks like you might be appending the whole rest of the token each time you loop - not just one character.

Comment: It handles the whitespace correctly.

Comment: Why are you writing all this complicated non standard code for this? Tokenizing a file on whitespace is as easy as `fstream f("file.txt"); string s; while(f >> s) cout << s << endl;`

Comment: `for (Pointer = Filestring.begin(); Pointer != Filestring.end(); advance(Pointer, 1)) if (!is_whitespace(0)) CurToken.append(*Pointer);` is just as concise even with the same variable and method names you use. IMHO the function is rather big given how little it does.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, oh right, I failed to notice `continue` :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the types of `CurToken` and `Pointer`? `CurToken` looks like a `std::string`. Is `Pointer` a `std::string*`? `append` has quite a few overloads. One of them is:

```
string& append ( const string& str );
```

If you want to hit that one you should get rid of the '&' to give you just the dereferenced pointer:

```
CurToken.append(*Pointer);
```

That should work, but remember that it'll append the whole string not just the character. If it doesn't you probably need to figure out which overload of `append()` it's hitting. If you want the first character only, try:

```
CurToken.append(1, (*Pointer)[0]);
```

Comment: Perfect. I think you best understood what I was trying to accomplish here, although I had to use `CurToken.append(1, (Pointer)[0]);`

Answer (score 7):

```
CurToken.append(&*Pointer);
```

Assuming `Pointer` is a pointer, that's equivalent to

```
CurToken.append(Pointer);
```

and will append the entire tail of the string onto `CurToken` (assuming it points to a C-style zero-terminated string; if there's no terminator then anything might happen). It looks like you just want to append the current character:

```
CurToken.append(*Pointer);
```

UPDATE: you say that `Pointer` is `std::string::iterator`. In that case, `&*Pointer` is still a pointer to the character; and `append` will still interpret it as a pointer to a C-style string. Since the characters in a string aren't necessarily terminated (although in practice they almost certainly will be, especially in a C++11 library), you've got undefined behaviour.

Comment: I would have assumed `Pointer` is a home-brewed smart pointer.

Comment: its `string::iterator    Pointer;`

Comment: @MarkB: Perhaps; quite a complicated one, since you can do arithmetic on it. Even so, `&*` would have the same effect as if it were a plain pointer.

Comment: @Headspin: OK, that will have the same effect as if it were a pointer, but with extra undefined behaviour. You still want `*Pointer` to get just the current character.